# Zend Framework 2 module white screen on Mac

Tags: zend-framework2

Zend Framework 2 project : some modules are white screen in Macbook MAMPP, but running properl y on LAMP or xampp environment. E_ALL is set

Comment: Check your error logs. White screen is usually a Server Error.

Comment: no recent errors on apache logs

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT)` there HAVE to be errors when there's a white screen. They may not be visible by your current settings, but they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Your renderer is probably generating errors that you are not seeing, try attaching yourself to  the EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR and the EVENT_RENDER_ERROR to find out what the Exception is.

Example Module.php:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(array(
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR,
            MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR,
            ), function(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event) use ($serviceManager) 
            {
                    if ($event->getError() === \Zend\Mvc\Application::ERROR_EXCEPTION)   
                    {
                            $exception = $event->getParam('exception');
                            // Do something with this Exception, like logging in.
                    }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` (which is recommended value for development environments) in `php.ini`
2. Set `display_errors = On` in `php.ini`
3. Restart php-fpm / http server
4. Reload the page.